# EF Core seed data Id not connecting, linked object is null

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a ton of seeds working - 10 models with hundreds of records each. Every one of those models has relationships with others. One alone has like 6. After all of that, one new property I've added has gummed up the system.

I have a `UserModel`, a `WorkOrderModel`, and a `WorkOrderViewModel`. The `WorkOrderViewModel` constructor receives a null `WorkOrderModel.CreatedBy` - all other properties seem to be working.

Models:

```
public class UserModel{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     //... irrelevant stuff
}
public class WorkOrderModel{
     public int Id {get;set;}

     [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
     public UserModel CreatedBy {get;set;}
     //... irrelevant stuff
}
```

Test data generator:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> WorkOrders(int l = 300) {
    var workOrders = new List<object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        workOrders.Add(new
        {
            Id = i + 1,
            CreatedById = 1,
        });
    }
    return workOrders;
}
```

And my context saving the data:

```
builder.Entity<WorkOrderModel>().HasData(TestDataGenerator.WorkOrders());
```

That runs smoothly until I call my API to get work orders.

```
public WorkOrderViewModel(WorkOrderModel model){
    Id = model.id;
    CreatedBy = model.CreatedBy.Id;
}

public int Id {get;set;}
public int CreatedBy {get;set;}
```

I did try to remove all migrations and start new with a fresh database. No change.

What's most perplexing is that I have about two dozen similar conversions (`model.ForeignEntity.Id -> viewModel.Property`) elsewhere, and they all work. I'm not sure if it's something in the seed generator or if I borked the relationship somehow?

Comment: Are you `Include`-ing `WorkOrderModel.CreatedBy` navigation property (these are not loaded automatically) in the query which then calls `WorkOrderViewModel` constructor? Can we see the usage?

Comment: @IvanStoev I both loathe and love you right now - that was it, I didn't have the `Include` on the service Get call I was making. If you want to pound out the answer I'll give you the kudos.

Comment: Heh, no problem - this is typical error with EF Core with many duplicates/similar questions, so I will pass :) Happy coding.